# Cocos2d selector already scheduled

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I cannot get my scheduler to repeat and i am getting the error below. What am i doing wrong? :(

I have also tried with the plain schedule instead of scheduleOnce but it throws the same.

```
CScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0000 to 0.0000
```

-

```
-(id) init
{

    if( (self=[super init] )) {
        [self scheduleOnce:@selector(method_name:) delay:3.0];
    }
}

- (void) method_name: (id) sender
{
  .. code
  [self scheduleOnce:@selector(method_name:) delay:10.0];
}
```

I am using cocos2d 2.1

Comment: I guess you have only one schedular, Unschedule all before scheduling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is valid code, the warning is logged only in case you did not actually wanted to reschedule the same selector with a different interval. If the msg bothers you, comment it out in cocos2d sources.

Update:

scheduled methods have to have the following signature:

```
-(void) method:(float)delta;
```

Your method takes an `id sender` as parameter.

Comment: Well i don't mind the msg really. Problem is that it does not call the selector again. :/ Bug?

Comment: oh i just see your problem... updating answer

Comment: I appreciate your effort in helping me but the problem still stands :( I am also getting the same result when trying to use the plain schedule with interval instead of delay if that is of any help.

Comment: setting the repeat to **kCCRepeatForever** of the initial schedule selector in the init solves the problem when using schedule instead of scheduleOnce. Should this make sense? :S

Comment: the sender parm is still wrong, as long as you're not using it it will work but it's effectively a garbage pointer

Comment: Is not id anything? Can i use ccTime instead of float or what is the difference?

Comment: id refers to "any NSObject reference" aka pointers, but not floats (aka ccTime)